# What's the meaning of "was bled of my bitterness"?

Tags: meaning

I checked Oxford Dictionary and "bleed" means:

- Lose blood from the body as a result of injury or illness.
- Draw blood from (someone), especially as a former method of treatment in medicine.
- Allow (fluid or gas) to escape from a closed system through a valve.
- print or be printed so that it runs off the page after trimming.

And "bitterness" means:

- Sharpness of taste; lack of sweetness
- Anger and disappointment at being treated unfairly; resentment.

But I can not understand the meaning of the phrase, and I don't know if it is an idiom or not. Does it mean *it reduced my angry*?

So, could you please tell me what the meaning of

> **was bled of my bitterness**

The text is:

> I remember strangely little of the hospital, or of how my brother looked.
>   I vaguely recall that his head was wrapped in gauze, and that when I asked
>   why, Mother said the doctors had performed a surgery, cutting into his
>   skull to relieve some pressure, or stop a bleed, or repair something—
>   actually, I can’t remember what she said. Shawn was tossing and turning
>   like a child with a fever. I sat with him for an hour. A few times his eyes
>   opened, but if he was conscious, he didn’t recognize me.
>   When I came the next day, he was awake. I walked into the room and he
>   blinked and looked at Mother, as if to check that she was seeing me, too.
>   “You came,” he said. “I didn’t think you would.” He took my hand and
>   then fell asleep.
>   I stared at his face, at the bandages wrapped around his forehead and
>   over his ears, and **was bled of my bitterness**. Then I understood why I
>   hadn’t come sooner. I’d been afraid of how I would feel, afraid that if he
>   died, I might be glad.

*Educated* by Tara Westover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The narrator uses the metaphor of bleeding in its old-fashioned sense as a putative healing process ("drawing blood from (someone), especially as a former method of treatment in medicine"), in this case for the bitterness he/she had felt previously. He/she no longer feel bitter towards his/her brother, seeing him helpless and bandaged.